# How to account for ensure_signed calls?

Tags: benchmarking

Let's say our pallet dispatchable returns `DispatchResultWithPostInfo`, where we are trying to manually calculate the weight, albeit with helpers obtained from benchmarking, but that's not relevant to the question. How do we account for the weight consumed by `ensure_signed` or `ensure_root` calls? Must they be benchmarked as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ensure_signed` and `ensure_root` are just a singular match statement.
They dont do any signature verification - that was already done prior and is included in the transaction base weight.
Otherwise if you want to be really pedantic, you can obviously add an `ensure_signed` call to your benchmark code or benchmark it independently and add the weight, but I dont think its necessary.

You can check their implementations; for example `ensure_signed`:

```rust
pub fn ensure_signed<OuterOrigin, AccountId>(o: OuterOrigin) -> Result<AccountId, BadOrigin>
where
    OuterOrigin: Into<Result<RawOrigin<AccountId>, OuterOrigin>>,
{
    match o.into() {
        Ok(RawOrigin::Signed(t)) => Ok(t),
        _ => Err(BadOrigin),
    }
}
```